# Why shell_exec does nothing

Tags: php, bash, shell, shell-exec

First of all yes this question is in many places on forums.
Anyway, in php I have this line `shell_exec("/var/www/html/downloadFile.sh " . $var3);` I call the script by sending arguments received from postman.
And well, the script does not run, but it does when I do it in the console `/var/www/html/downloadFile.sh arg`

I've checked everywhere and couldn't fix it. From execute permissions to php configuration. In the script I print everything to a log file, but nothing happens when I do. However it does when I run it on console.

If someone needs more information, feel free to write it in order to solve this

Comment: What is the output from `shell_exec`?  E.g. `$output = $shell_exec(...`  I personally always use `exec()` with the `$output` array because "It is not possible to detect execution failures using this [shell_exec] function.".  See Note in the Return Value section of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Did you check the phpinfo() output? Most likely the `shell_exec` is disabled in the PHP config. Check the [`disable_functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive.